# Debug code in Napa ( Office 365 Online)

Tags: office-365, debugging, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have written a code to add an item in list in Office 365 using Napa. I have used client object model in the code. But the item doesnt get added in the list. Is there any way to debug the code in Online?

Answer (score 3):

Napa was created with the objective to facilitate a 'lightweight, in-browser experience' to build SharePoint or Office web app in the same browser where they would run. Ergo, it was designed to kind of complement the inherent features of the browser.

For advanced tooling, one would have to turn to Visual Studio 2012

You can debug code like any javascript: 
In IE, 'F12 developer tools' could be used to debug the JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

[MSDN Link for IE 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Also, relevant link for IE 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Link to source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7e18efbf-0ab8-4637-b572-1bf32b539b8c/how-to-debug-in-napa?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

Since your app uses mainly (well only) javascript, your only option is to debug the javascript code with for example fiddler or the development tools in your browser. You have no direct access to the internal ULS logs in Office 365 I'm afraid